# Whats is the difference between AWS ELB and Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I am new to AWS Route53 and trying to brush up some of the basics. I have a question that might sound silly.

Lets say i have a public load balancer created with its DNS (AWS auto generated). Now i went ahead and got my corporate company to create a CName for the actual ELB A record, so say that CNAME is `www.my-website.com`.

Now when users start browsing www.my-website.com, their router DNS directly know where this public www.my-website.com is hosted and then once the DNS resolution happens, the request is directly forwarded to my ELB that has that CName to it.

Now all this is good but i would also like to play with Route53 here, so i go ahead and use Route53 to create a hosted zone and add my domain `www.my-website.com` under it and then create a record set with alias pointing to my actual ELB followed by rest of the configuration.

Now when someone hits `www.my-website.com` on their browser will the request directly go to the ELB or go to Route53 that will then route it to that ELB?

Comment: Route53 is nothing more than DNS. An alias in route53 is basically a CNAME, but AWS returns it as an A record.

Comment: So as per my question, where will the request first go? Will it be directly to the ELB because that is associated with that CNAME www.my-website.com, or will that go to Route53 since its also associated with the ELB using recordset alias?

Comment: @Ashley the DNS request will go to Route53 to resolve the domain name. The HTTP request will go directly to the load balancer, because DNS servers don't handle HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary of what these services provides is below:

- Route 53 is a DNS Provider provided as a service by AWS. The functionality you're describing using is to store your DNS records within it for resolution.
- An ELB is an appliance to distribute traffic across multiple nodes.

With your records in Route 53 the below journey takes place:

- When a client in the browser attempts to go to `www.example.com` it will first check in its internal cache for any previously stored values for the domain, if theres a value it will be evaluated against a TTL to see if it has been expired.
- If no value or expired the client will connect to the root domain, then the top level domain continuing until it finds the DNS provider for your domain (`.` -> `.com.` -> `example.com.`.
- Once it finds this DNS provider it will query for your domain, if it matches it will return the resolution value and the TTL.
- If the value is that of a CNAME (such as an ELB) this process will begin again to resolves the IP address(es) for your hostname. This IP address will be cached by your local client.

If you're using Route 53 and an ELB one advantage would be to use Alias records they actually set your domain record to the IP address which improves the speed of DNS resolution.

So in summary Route 53 is only contacted if the client does not know the resolution value for your domain.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. The client doesn't walk domains, the resolver your client queries does that.

Comment: Thanks Chris and others. If the DNS is self created by AWS and not registered through Route53, and then the Cname is created and associated with the A record of my ELB, if some client on public internet browses www.my-website.com, why would any request go to Route53?

Comment: It would only hit Route 53 in the DNS resolution chain if the name server of either `www.my-website.com` or its CNAME record resolved to Route 53. All AWS resource domains such as load balancers for example will resolve to Route 53. You can always test this by adding the ELB to https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/ and viewing the NS value.

Comment: So in my case if dns is not created via route53 but i want to use it for failover to other region where i have replicated my app with its ELB (lets say its B while A is my ELB in primary region), will that work or request will never make its way to route53 so that it can then decide whether it needs to route request to region one ELB or region two ELB?

Comment: The Route 53 functionality you're describing of having a failover by DNS requires that your DNS provider is Route 53. Alternatively for failovers not based on DNS you can use CloudFront: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html or Global Accelerator: https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/?blogs-global-accelerator.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&blogs-global-accelerator.sort-order=desc&aws-global-accelerator-wn.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&aws-global-accelerator-wn.sort-order=desc

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think that is what i was looking for and it says under the AWS doc under prerequisite that though "You can use Route 53 as your domain registrar, or you can use a different registrar" however, "you need Route 53 as the DNS service for the domain".
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html.
So in my case i will have to switch my domain to Route53 before i can use it to route traffic to the actual ELBs that serve traffic to my app servers. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You will need to switch it if you want to use alias records or failover yes. Otherwise you can CNAME to you ELB in any provider